# Can you differentiate between RFID types?

Tags: bluetooth, rfid

Background:
We have a project were we want to be able to assign a scanned RFID to an object in a database. The scanners, using Bluetooth, will vary wildly, but will use either UHF or LF, but at first pass, we couldn't see a way to tell the difference. The reader itself or the tags themselves, don't seem to attach any extra data regarding this. So we've resigned ourselves to having a manual toggle in our software.

But are there other ways?

Aside from frequency ranges being different, is there something inherent to a RFID tag that tells us if it is LF or UHF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your host doesn't interface with the tag itself, it's up to the reader to do that.

I'm pretty sure they somehow give you that info. Or a certain scanner type can just read one type of tag, and that will tell you.

This isn't something you can solve in software.